# InvalidKeyException using ECPublicKey

Tags: java, encryption, public-key-encryption, pki, key-generator

I'm getting the following exception when I try to encrypt a byte array with a EC public key:

> java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this
>   key:
>                                          sun.security.ec.ECPublicKeyImpl

This exception is generated when I call `Cipher.init()`. The lines below show what I did in my program:

```
ECPublicKey publicKey ;
ECPrivateKey privateKey;

//Generating key paire (public and private keys) 
    KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC", "SunEC");
    SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN");

    keyGen.initialize(571, random);
    KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
    privateKey = (ECPrivateKey) pair.getPrivate();
    publicKey = (ECPublicKey) pair.getPublic();

// get an AES cipher object with CTR encription mode 
   Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");

// encrypt the sharedSecret using the public key
   cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);**
   byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(data);
```

Must I add a provider to support this public key?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the source of this exception. The problem was initialization of cipher :

```
//This is the wrong initialization
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");

//This is the right initialization
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding","SunJCE");
```

But now, i have another exception which is (it is less important than the previous one) :

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid AES key length: 170 bytes
```

So what must I use as encrypting algorithm with ECDSA public key now ?

Answer (score 0):

ECDSA is not used for encryption 
rather you use RSA / Symetric cipher

Answer (score 0):

```
  KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
  keygen.init(128);
  key = keygen.generateKey();
String plain_input = "Hush-a-bye, baby, on the tree top,When the wind blows" ; 
  //encryption
  cipher = Cipher.getInstance(""AES/EBC/PKCS5Padding");
  cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
  byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plain_input.getBytes("UTF8"));

  //decryption
  cipher = Cipher.getInstance(""AES/EBC/PKCS5Padding");
  cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
  byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
  String plain_output = new String(decrypted, "UTF8");
```